# Retrieve range of data based on weeknumber

Tags: excel

I'm setting up a database containing information of production runs. Each production run usually takes place within 24 h, leading to about 7 runs/week. Multiple values and variables are entered into the database, giving an idea how well/poorly each run went. I want to visualize this information in graphs, which give a weekly view (so 7 runs in 1 graph). My idea was to have a 2nd worksheet where I can input a week number, having Excel then show all runs (and all their relevant info) that took place in that week. This set area could then be used to fetch info for the graphs from. Idea being, I input a different week number, the values in this area change based on the runs for the new week and the graph looking at this are will automatically update.

I've been working with `HLOOKUP` based on dates, which works fine if 1 run takes place on 1 day.

Example: `=HLOOKUP(D$2,'Run Values'!$C$6:$XFD$54,3,TRUE)`, where `D$2`is the date on which the run took place, `'Run Values!$C$6:$XFD$54` is the range where the values for each run can be stored (2nd worksheet), & `3` is the row for this particular piece of info (this value changes per row that I use the HLOOKUP in, depending on what I'm looking for).

However, when for some reason multiple runs took place on the same date (which occasionally happens), it only retrieves the first run encountered for that run. This is probably because I'm checking per date.

Is there a way to either improve this code (using `HLOOKUP`) to get it to do what I want it to do? Or is there an alternative (maybe more easy) way to get to where I want to be?

Sample data consists of weeks placed next to each other (1 week of data here):

| 43 | 43 | 43 | 43 | 43 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/10/2021 | 26/10/2021 | 26/10/2021 | 27/10/2021 | 28/10/2021 |
| 659 | 660 | 660 | 661 | 662 |
| 879 | 880PUR | 881 | 882 | 883 |
| 34157 | 23034 | 27224 | 41740 | 40062 |
| 29.06% | 29.75% | 28.29% | 27.51% | 26.57% |
| 12.58 | 9.65 | 9.65 | 14.20 | 16.17 |

I'm looking to extract the 1st through 4th row of the green values, 2nd through 9th row of the blue values, all of the light orange and all of the dark orange values for an entire week, and all this for 1 week of data at a time. So if I would request week 43 on my second worksheet, then it would retrieve them from this data base as such:
[image]
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with some sample data and expected results

Comment: @Birel does this edit help out?

Comment: You're getting there. The sample data we need are data that we can easily copy to replicate the problem, then provide you with an answer. We don't have time to type up the sample data and secondly we don't understand your data as well as you. So provide us data that we can easily copy to give you an answer quickly. If you want to see an example of how this might look, have a look at some the questions I asked historically and how I put the question, etc.

Comment: @Birel Did not get it to work quite like you managed in your questions, did manage to get it in table for readers to copy. Adjusted the output based on the smaller sample data size.

Comment: Yes that's way better. Is this data always stored in Excel or is it stored in SQL or similar...? If the data is stored in Excel, my suggestion would be to create a macro that gets the data from another sheet or file. If it's in SQL, I would recommend you to plugin excel via ODBC or OLAP query to acquire the desired results...

Comment: It's always stored in Excel. Normally I would write a macro to do this, however company policy prohibits this. The file will be used over numerous PC's/users, in which case the company forbids use of Macro's. So it has to be formula based.

Comment: The only way you can get it to refresh the way you want it to is with a macro unfortunately.